# getch not reading keyboard input

Tags: c++, c, curses, getch, keyboard-input

Trying to get user input for a simple terminal game. I am on Mac OS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int ch;
    while (ch != 113)
    {
        ch = getch();
        std::cout << ch << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I'm trying to simply print my keystrokes, but `ch = getch()` doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't wait for a keypress and `std::cout << ch << std::endl` just prints -1 repeatedly. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: [Turn up your warning level.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hLb6z8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first call `initscr` before any other curses functions.
http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int ch;
    initscr(); // <----------- this
    while (ch != 113)
    {
        ch = getch();
        std::cout << ch << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's responding to keystrokes now. I had a feeling it was something small like that.